# Set Comprehension in python

Tags: python, set

In Python3 I wrote a simple one line code as follows :

```
{ 2*x  for x in {1,2,3,4} }
```

but I m getting answer like this (order changed).

```
{8, 2, 4, 6}
```

Why I am getting answer `{8,2,4,6}` instead of `{2,4,6,8}`?

Answer (score 8):

That's because sets don't have any order. They're unordered collection.

help on `set`:

> Build an **unordered** collection of unique elements.

If you want the order to be preserved then you can use `list`, `tuple` or `collections.OrderedDict` here.

Answer (score 5):

Because a set has no fixed order. Quoting [the set documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

> A *set* object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.

Use a list or tuple if you require ordering, or use an `OrderedDict()` object to create unique keys that preserve ordering:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

ordered_unique_values = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(2*x for x in (1,2,3,4)))
```