# Python Set Comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I'm just starting out learning python set comprehensions. Why does `{ 2**x for x in {0,1,2,3,4} }` return `{8, 1, 2, 4, 16}` instead of the ordered `{1, 2, 4, 8, 16}`?

Comment: Python sets are not ordered; there's no "instead of", since those are the same set.

Comment: And of [python set changes element order?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9792664) and [Set Comprehension in python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17446318)

Comment: Note http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/

Comment: I think this has been updated in python 3 to be ordered more often

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematically speaking, sets do not have an order. When displaying or iterating over a set, Python obviously needs to provide a particular order, but this order is arbitrary and not to be relied on. The order is, however, fixed for a particular set; iterating over the same, *unmodified* set will produce the same order each time.